# Which class to use for execution of a regulary task? Service vs IntentSerivce vs WorkManager

Tags: java, android

I would like to execute a task regurlary, currently implemented as `runnable`. The next time of execution is set in the code itself, which varys from 8 to 90 minutes delay. It is not important that it is executed exactly at this time, some minutes delay are no problem. The task comprise a donwload of a website (`HTML`) and the extraction of a string. No UI is required at this time, but the task should be executed if the app is not running, too.

I search on the internet and found several opportunities: `Thread`, `AsyncTask`, `ExecutorService`, `ScheduledExecutorService`, `Service`, `IntentService`, `WorkManager`, `AlarmManager`,...
I would like to know which one of this could be recommended to my case.

So far I tried a `Service` in combination with Executor, ExecutorService and `ScheduledExecutorService`. Unfortunately the task was executed with a delay up to 60 minutes, which is too much.

Code sample:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);   

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {

    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do something regulary
            scheduler.schedule(this,getNewInterval(),MILLISECONDS);
        }
    };

  //create notification, notification channel, startForegorund()


    scheduler.schedule(runnable,1,MINUTES);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: "some minutes delay are no problem" -- the delay may range from minutes to hours, depending on the state of the device and the version of Android that it is running on. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background). "Unfortunately the task was executed with a delay up to 60 minutes, which is too much" -- then client-side polling is not going to be a reliable solution for you. Have your server send FCM messages to the app when the data changes.

Comment: Would you mind to make some effort to post your code, please?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have no direct access to the server. Is there no opportunity to execute this service with highest priority ignoring battery consumption and performance?

Comment: Not directly. Android is a consumer operating system, and consumers have said very loudly that they are tired of apps draining the battery. So, Google has modified Android to suit, and various device manufacturers have gone even further. You can go into the Settings app and add your app to the battery optimization whitelist (e.g., in Android 10, that's Apps & notifications > Special app access > Battery optimization). That may help somewhat. However, there is no requirement for the user to do that, and certain devices will still constrain your app (mostly Chinese brands like Huawei).